# babelify pipe results in: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/.../jquery.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to create a single js file containing jquery, bootstrap and reactjs components using a gulp task:

app.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var HelloWorld = require('./Application.jsx');
var $, jQuery = require('../../libraries/jquery/dist/jquery');
var bootstrap = require('../../libraries/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Application />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
browserify('./public/javascripts/src/app.jsx')
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts/build/'));
});
```

When running gulp, I get the following message:

> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/Users/.../jquery/dist/jquery.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

How I design the `gulp` task, so that `jquery` and `bootstrap` does not pass the `babelify` pipe?

Comment: Why not use `jQuery` and `bootstrap-sass` from npm? Then these would be automatically ignored.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add an `ignore` key to your babelify configuration so that it looks like something along the lines of:

```
 .transform(babelify, {ignore: ['./libraries/**/*'], presets:["es2015", "react"]})
```

This should keep bableify from messing with your lib files that are already es5/minified/production ready.

*(You may need to adjust the path a little bit... not 100% of your project structure)*